# I am having trouble when opening a form, in access, getting it to go to maximum screen size

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access db with 3 users.  I have created all the code on my workstation and the users each open a different front end on their workstation (the code is maintained on a central server).

I have tried a few different ways in the code to open the default form when I open Access on their workstation.  I have used form_load and form_open procedures with doCmd.Maximize.

Here is the problem: when I open either one of the front ends on my workstation the form maximizes, so I suspect its not a code problem.  When I open Access at the workstations, the default forms only open to the size I created, say 5" x 5".  However, if I then put the form into 'design' mode followed by 'form' mode the forms will take up the entire screen i.e. they do maximize. It is only a problem when Access is started at their workstations and the default form loads.

Can someone point me to a setting somewhere or a VBA code variation that will maximize the form when it is loaded?  All 3 workstations are running Windows 10.

Comment: You may try the Activate event of the form, but - in my opinion - it's a bit rude to demand the user's full screen estate (except on tablets, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maximize Access window itself, not just your form.
Copy this to some pulbic module:

```vb
' Put at the top of the module:
Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Boolean
Global Const SW_MAXIMIZE = 3

' Function to get window handle of Access application:
Function GetAccesshWnd()
    Dim hWnd As Long, hWndAccess As Long
    ' Get the handle to the currently active window.
    hWnd = GetActiveWindow()
    hWndAccess = hWnd
    ' Find the top window without a parent window.
    While hWnd <> 0
        hWndAccess = hWnd
        hWnd = GetParent(hWnd)
    Wend
    GetAccesshWnd = hWndAccess
End Function
```

and this in form_load event:

```vb
ShowWindow GetAccesshWnd(), SW_MAXIMIZE
```

Comment: thank you, I will code it tonight and test it in the morning

Comment: I tried the code but it stops because I haven't declared the functions GetActiveWindow or GetParent and I'm sorry but I do not know what the proper declarations should be.  By the way, I am using Access 2016

Comment: @Les, my bad, i forgot another two declarations. Updated the post.

Comment: Don't use integers unless necessary (WinApi-Calls), use longs. Handles won't fit to integer. Don't use delaration shortcuts as`%`(short for`As Integer`). Use [Windows API Viewer](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/dennis/windowsapiviewer.htm) for api declarations and be aware of `Application.hWndAccessApp`

Comment: @viilpe Sorry, but it didn't work.  The default form still comes up at it's designed size i.e. 5"x5".  Behind it, Access does take up the whole screen.  Obviously, I don't want the users clicking on it, by going beyond the boundaries of the form.  Maybe, instead I could minimize Access so it is less than the size of the form.  Is this possible?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Thanks, I will investigate.

Comment: @viilpe It turns out that my form had some kind of corruption.  I copied a good form and then took all the controls from the bad form and copied them to the good form.  It works fine now.  Sometimes these corruptions are subtle and I do not know what triggers them.  Thanks for your suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

Even I usually avoid`DoCmd`, maximizing Access Application window is a one liner with:

```
Apllication.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMaximize 'Maximize the MS Access Application
```

Or with ShowWindow (x86 and x64) and Application.hWndAccessApp:

```vb
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" Alias "ShowWindow" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
#End If
Private Const SW_MAXIMIZE = 3

Public Sub MaximizeAccessApp(Optional ByRef app As Access.Application)
  If app Is Nothing Then
    Set app = Application
  End If
  ShowWindow app.hWndAccessApp, SW_MAXIMIZE
End Sub
```

This can be used without argument for current Access Aplication or pass another Access Instance to maximze its window.

```vb
Private Sub TestMaximizeAccessApp()
  Dim app As Object
  Set app = CreateObject("Access.Application")
  app.OpenCurrentDatabase ("path/to/db")

  MaximizeAccessApp app
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, same as before.  Maybe I've done something with the settings for the form that I'm unaware of.  Access maximizes but the form does not. I will try another form from the db as the default display form and see what happens.

Comment: Any other code executed at startup? You can use`Form_Resize`event to see if it gets restored`Debug.Print "resized to:" & Me.WindowWidth & " " & Me.WindowHeight`

Comment: The only code I have been using is me.move -10,-10 and docmd.maximize in the form_load procedure. This is all I use in my other forms.

Comment: I have had problems in the past with forms somehow becoming corrupt.  I have copied the default display form from another db, removed all the controls, and copied the controls from the form that was giving me grief onto the form that worked properly. And it works fine now.  I do not know why forms work one day and become corrupt the next.  It hasn't happened in quite a long time but the only solution has been to start with a fresh form. I thank you for looking into this for me.

Comment: Corruption of front-end should not be a weekly topic. If it is you do something wrong. Use [Application.LoadFromText/SaveasText](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=296459) to get a repaired db. Now evaulate the reason for corruption. If I remeber right (last corrupt db was 3 years ago), that can be caused by sharing the  front-end (every user should have its own copy), Look at [Preventing corruption](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-25.html)